# How to convert list of object to another list object using streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

The below code snippet, has been implemented without lambda expressions.

How to implement the same functionality using lambda expressions?

```
public class Java8EmpTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<Emp> empInList = Arrays.asList(new Emp(1, 100), new Emp(2, 200), new Emp(3, 300));
        List<Emp> afterSalayHikeInJava7 = new ArrayList<>();
        // old way
        for (Emp emp : empInList) {
            afterSalayHikeInJava7.add(new Emp(emp.getId(), emp.getSalary() * 100));
        }
        afterSalayHikeInJava7.stream()
                .forEach(s -> System.out.println("Id :" + s.getId() + " Salary :" + s.getSalary()));
    }
}

class Emp {
    private int id;
    private int salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    Emp(int id, int salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.map()`...

Comment: .map() - will help to convert one type to another type. correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Simple use `map()` method in stream api and collect results:

```
  List<Emp> employe = Arrays.asList(new Emp(1, 100), new Emp(2, 200), new Emp(3, 300));
  List<Emp> employeRise = employe.stream()
                                 .map(emp -> new Emp(emp.getId(), emp.getSalary * 100))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
  employeRise.stream()
            .forEach(s -> System.out.println("Id :" + s.getId() + " Salary :" + s.getSalary()));
```

Answer (score 10):

`map()` each `Emp` of the input `List` to a new `Emp` and then `collect()` to a `List`:

```
List<Emp> afterSalayHike = 
    empInList.stream()
             .map(emp->new Emp(emp.getId(), emp.getSalary() * 100))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks @Eran. Perfect. Since i am new and start learning . i wil post more question to get clarify

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic but looks intresting. How does it looks like if you are using Java 9 flatMap() ?

Comment: @NikolaiHristov `flatMap()` exists in Java 8 too, but why would you want to use `flatMap()` here?

Comment: Nevermind @Eran. I came across this question while I was looking for examples with flatMap and I did not know it was available in Java 8.